# Nokogiri find text in paragraphs

Tags: ruby, string, nokogiri

I want to replace the inner_text in all paragraphs in my XHTML document.

I know I can get all text with Nokogiri like this

```
doc.xpath("//text()")
```

But I want only operate on text in paragraphs, how I can select all text in paragraphs without affecting eventually existent anchor texts in links ?

```
#For example : <p>some text <a href="/">This should not be changed</a> another one</p>
```

Comment: should that last tag be `</p>`, to close the `<p>` tag, rather than `</a>`?

Comment: Selecting, by any definition, shouldn't _affect_ anything. What do you mean by "select without affecting"?

Comment: @michaelmichael - sure, You're right, I have corrected the last closing tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For text which is an immediate child of a paragraph use //p/text()

```
irb> h = '<p>some text <a href="/">This should not be changed</a> another one</p>'
=> ...
irb> doc = Nokogiri::HTML(h)
=> ...
irb> doc.xpath '//p/text()'
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80ac2e04 "some text ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80ac26c0 " another one">]
```

For text which is a descendent (immediate or not) of a paragraph use //p//text().  To exclude those texts which have an anchor as a parent, you could just subtract them off.

```
irb> doc.xpath('//p//text()') - doc.xpath('//p//a/text()')
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80ac2e04 "some text ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80ac26c0 " another one">]
```

There is probably a way to do it with one call, but my xpath knowledge doesn't go that deep.